# Microsoft Excel hyperlink function to a specific location in a Word doc

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a long column of numbers in Excel that I have mail merged to a Word doc.  I would like to write a function in Excel that will hyperlink each cell from this column to its corresponding mail merged number location in the Word doc.  Although I can do this manually for each cell using either the hyperlink function or simply the hyperlink tab, I hope someone can share with me how to write a function in the first cell that I can simply copy and past down the entire column and be done.  My specific snag is getting the link location in the function to "read" the number in the cell as the location number in the Word doc.  For example:

I want to link cell A5 (that contains the number 338-229-4392) to that number's location in the mail merged Word document called "Report" which is located in the same file folder as the Excel spreadsheet.  I use the following formula successfully but must manually enter the location number:

=HYPERLINK("[data\Report.docx]338-229-4392",A5)

Comment: I see two problems here: (a) I think you will need to use VBA to do this. (b) to link to a specific point inside a Word document, you need to link to a bookmark, which cannot be named "338-229-4392" and will not be created by a typical MailMerge. So I am not sure how your link is working at the moment!